How to upload files in Azure storage using System Identity when Allow Storage key account key access is disabled
I am using the following PowerShell code in Azure Runbook to upload files to blob storage, but I encountered an error: "Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account." I have added the Azure Runbook system identity key to the storage account, but I am still getting this error.

$AzureContext = ( Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
$ctx = (Get -AzStorageAccount -Name Testadlsprod -ResourceGroupName TestProd).Context
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\Upload

foreach($file in $files)
{
  $foldername = "Backup\Production\"+$file.Name
  Set-AzStorageBloBContent -File $file.FullName -Container backup  -Blob $folderName -Context $ctx
}

I am using the following PowerShell code to upload files to blob storage, but I encountered an error: "Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account." I have added the Azure Runbook system identity key to the storage account, but I am still getting this error.

If you use managed identity login, you need UseConnectedAccount to get $context. (role assignment should be completed in advance )
Below is a sample for get blob for simple but also suitable for uploading blobs
$storageAccountName = "wbsatestxxx"

$containerName = "test"
$blobName = "test.txt"

Connect-AzAccount -Identity

$context_login_account = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

Write-Host "get detail using login account sa context"
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $context_login_account


Thanks for providing solution. I am getting below error after executing above code This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission . Which permission is required to execute code?

@hi Lucidity, try to assign the managed identity the role Storage Blob Data Contributor

One quick question for my knowledge . Can we connect storage account using user assigned managed identity ? If yes then how to connect with User Assigned MI

Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity.ClientId  specify the user assigned MI client Id. identity login command not work in local. but works in runbook, vm which enabled user MI

check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-12.1.0#example-6-connect-using-managed-service-identity-login-and-clientid
